# Конвертация объекта в строку параметров для URL в JavaScript

Tags: node.js, javascript

Здравствуйте, сообщество.
Мне необходимо конвертнуть объект в строку параметров для URL типа вот так:

Объект на входе:

```
var obj = {
   a: 4, 
   b: { 
      c:5, 
      d: { 
         e: 33, 
         f:13
      }, 
      g:1
   },
   h: [1,2]
};
```

Строка параметров на выходе:

```
a=4&b[c]=5&b[d][e]=33&b[d][f]=13&b[g]=1&h[]=1&h[]=2
```

Строка параметров в более читаемом виде для сравнения c исходным объектом:

```
a=4   &   
b[c]=5   &   
b[d][e]=33   &   
b[d][f]=13   &   
b[g]=1    &   
h[]=1   &   
h[]=2
```

Пишу программу на Node.JS. Если вы знаете такую функцию, или пакет с такой функцией, или писали самостоятельно такое, поделитесь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: JSON.stringify(), передача на сервер, а на сервере уже обратная операция.  
Это конечно не ответ на непосредственно поставленный вопрос, но зато без велосипедов.

Comment: Тут дело немножко в другом. Пишу довольно сложное приложение и на странице выводится, к примеру, несколько таблиц по-странично. Т.е. ода таблица может быть открыта на 5 странице, а вторая на 2. Когда пользователь нажимает на pager'е на страницу №3 у таблицы 2, то в этой таблице 2 должна открыться таблица 3, а у первой так и остаться 5ая. А страницы определяются из url: например pager1=5&pager2=2, но таблицы о существовании друг друга не должны знать. Поэтому был выбран путь что кнопка страницы будет брать объект req.query и менять значение своего педжера в нем, и конвертировать в ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам написал требуемую функцию. ) Для желающих узнать правильный ответ:

```
function encode(obj){
    function objToArray(obj, path){
        if(!path) path = [];
        var result = [];

        for(var i in obj)
            if(typeof obj[i] == 'object')
                result = result.concat(objToArray(obj[i], [].concat(path, [i])));
            else
                result.push({path: [].concat(path, [i]), value: obj[i]});

        return result;
    }

    function arrayToURL(array){
        var vars = [];
        array.forEach(function(item, i){
            var parts = [];
            item.path.forEach(function(part, i){
                parts.push(i == 0 ? part : ('[' + part + ']'));
            });

            vars.push([parts.join(''), item.value].join('='));
        });

        return vars.join('&');
    }

    return arrayToURL(objToArray(obj));
}

module.exports = encode;
```

Если на вход подать вот такой объект:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: {
            d: 'sd',
            r: 'qqq'
        },
        h: 9
    },
    zz: [1,2,3]
};
```

То выходе получается вот такая строка:

```
a=1&b[c][d]=sd&b[c][r]=qqq&b[h]=9&zz[0]=1&zz[1]=2&zz[2]=3
```

Всем спасибо! )

Comment: Что-то не могу понять как теперь закрыть вопрос..

Comment: А зачем его закрывать? Может через полчаса кто-нибудь выложит свой более оптимальный код, или указание на стандартную функцию делающее тоже самое.  
Или через год это произойдет, не суть.

Comment: Ну раз так.. ладно тогда.. )